# Unable to install Azure Toolkit for Eclipse

Tags: azure-app-service-plans, azure-java-sdk

Anyone out there who has successfully installed Azure Toolkit for Eclipse? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/eclipse/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation) is the documentation I am trying to follow.

Per this documentation at step 4, **Azure Toolkit for Java** should be listed for installation. I do not see this option and only see Team Explorer Everywhere.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise (64 bit) and have tried the same steps (per the link posted above) with Eclipse Neon, Eclipse Mars and Eclipse Oxygen. None of the attempts showed me **Azure Toolkit for Java** option. Has anyone managed to get this working?

Also is there another way to create Java projects for App Service. Perhaps using a standard Maven template?

Answer (score 0):

After several failed attempts to install Azure Toolkit for eclipse, I finally deployed the app by FTPing the package to App Service.

Putting this here just in case someone is struggling with the Azure Toolkit.

Some useful links.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-java-add-app